# Variables defined only once per thread instead of once every source file in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I have a 186MB variable that for speed reasons has to be defined once per thread. The problem is that a `extern` variable defines it only once at all, and a `thread_local` variable defines to much times per thread, and i'm hitting the RAM limit in my program.

So I have my variable declared in `precalculated_values.hpp`, a header that will be needed in several parts of the project.

```
thread_local const std::map<std::string, unsigned> clients_register = readReg();
```

but `register` is going to be defined once every single `cpp` that needs it, and it is very big (but i need to have it ONCE per thread, so i cannot use `extern`).

How would you make a variable be defined only once per thread?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/thread_local

Comment: Yes, that is exactly how it defines multiple times per thread (once for every cpp that includes it) (my bad for write 'static' insteads of thread_local' in the question)

Comment: please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles i thought in this case was not necessary, but of course.

Comment: Where is this variable declared? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles more asking for a technical information than for a specific fix, I don't see how I could make my example "reproducible"

Comment: You can combine `thread_local` with `extern`. Just add `extern` to the declaration in the header file and define the variable in one of the source code files. From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) : "The `thread_local` keyword [...] can be combined with static or extern to specify internal or external linkage."

Comment: **Declare** the variable in the header file using `extern` **and** `thread_local` keywords without initializer. **Define** the variable in the source file using `thread_local` keyword and initializer.

Comment: @Tsyvarev didnt know that was possible. Good solution!

Comment: Also I wonder what happens if you use `register` as an identifier. Didn't the compiler somehow message you? It is a C++ keyword (though not a very useful one) and I would recommend you not to use it as identifier.

Comment: @JakobStark right

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: changed answer based on comments

If the map is const, the data does not change, and you should be able to get away with a single instance across all threads.

```
//cpp
const std::map<std::string, unsigned> & getClientsRegister() {
  const static std::map<std::string, unsigned> clients_register = readReg();
  return clients_register;
}   

//header:
const std::map<std::string, unsigned> & getClientsRegister();
```

If the readReg somehow return different data for each thread you can substitute the static for thread_local.

Keep in mind that thread_local may not play nice on all platforms:
On MSVC the thread_local is same as __declspec( thread ) and has some limitations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/storage-classes-cpp?view=msvc-170
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/parallel/thread-local-storage-tls?view=msvc-170

Comment: OP specifically wants it not to be `static`, which is implied here by `const` anyway by default. `extern` and `static` together makes no sense.

Comment: Not only does it make no sense, it is not allowed to have more than one storage class specifier (except combinations with `thread_local`)

Comment: True, whoopsie: meant  something along the lines of a function returning the a const reference to a static internal (in the case where the data should be read only and same across alll threads, The second sample should still work. allthough i would advise using a function to return it as global scope initialization order is not defined.